# Send an Email Quick Action automatically replies instead of starting a new email

Tags: lightning, email, chatter, quickaction, chatter-feed-tracking

I have Created a send email quick action on Case Object and I have also put the chatter component on the lightning page with this quick on it. Everytime I try to use the quick action to write an email it starts it as a reply to the previous email on the case instead of started a new email. Is there any setting to ensure it starts a new email instead of replying to the old one?